# restarting apache using python causes port change

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, python

i'm using python bottle web framework to create a service manager
so i've created endpoints for services re/starting / stopping
the wired thing that happens when i'm using

`os.system('service apache2 restart')`

or

`os.system('/etc/init.d/apache2 restart')`

the apache takes over the port of my bottle app so if i'm running `lsof -i :8080` (8080 is my bottle app port) i see

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  27396     root    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27426     root    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27428 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27429 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27430 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27432 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27433 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 27435 www-data    3u  IPv4 1298282      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

the file /etc/apache2/ports has the following

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and of course if i'm running the same command in the shell all works as expected

**note: the python script is running as root**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default, child processes inherit file descriptors of their parent.

Since your web app has this port open, it trickles down for the `os.system` request to the running apache web server.

You need to alter your python code to do the following.

- Call `os.fork()`
- Close the file descriptor of the listening server port your web app works with. (note do  *not* call `shutdown` on it.
- Call your `os.system()` request.
- Exit your forked process.

Newer versions of python introduced a default behaviour of adding the `FD_CLOEXEC` property on all file descriptors to avoid this behaviour. You can do the same yourself on the listening socket too using the `fcntl` module, but that may break other aspects of your application so you would need to test for this.

Comment: could you explain the following:

`Close the file descriptor of the listening server port your web app works with. (note do not call shutdown on it.`

Comment: This bottle app you have uses a file descriptor to represent the listening socket it created. You need to close it in a child process before calling `os.system`. If you were to call `shutdown` on the socket it would break the stream for all applications that are still using the file descriptor so you do not want to do that.

Comment: it uses the generic SimpleHTTPServer which uses the SocketServer and i can't seem to figure out how to get that file descriptor from that